# JavaScript Как в функции bind() связать параметры не по порядку?

Tags: javascript, haskell

Как связать переданные параметры в bind с аргументами не по порядку?
Например, как сделать чтобы в таком примере:

```
let logWithEnding = console.log.bind(null, "\nThe End!");

logWithEnding("The Start");
```

"The End!" выводилось после "The Start", а не перед.
В Haskell я бы мог сделать что-то вроде:

```
logWithEnding start = consoleLog start "The End!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете и в JavaScript сделать точно то же самое, что и в Haskell:

```
let logWithEnding = start => console.log(start, "\nThe End!");
```

Или длинным синтаксисом:

```
function logWithEnding(start) { console.log(start, "\nThe End!") }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!